# Changing the target directory of command cd ~

Tags: command-line, server, apache2

Goodday,

At the moment I am working on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. When I want to go to my home directory ("*/home/tensineer*") via the command "**cd ~**", it sets me to the directory "***/var/www***".
Guess something has gone off when installing Apache, but my question now is: how do I get "**cd ~**"  to set me back to my own home directory (creating an alias didn't do the trick in my home *.bashrc*).

Cheers!

Comment: Does whoami (terminal command) return tensineer os something else?

Comment: @Broadsworde yes, "whoami" returns the username "tensineer".

Comment: What does 'echo $HOME' return?

Comment: @Broadsworde "echo $HOME" returns the apache dir ('/var/www'). Setting $HOME to "/home/tensineer" makes "cd ~" go to my home directory, indeed. But I hope that won't interfere with Apache (I have no clue why the HOME dir was set to /var/www, I guess the apache installer did a trick on that).
Thanks for your tips! :)

Comment: Check your `/etc/passwd` file and change your location for `tensineer` user but for this you must have `sudo` priviledge.

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal Done. I saw the location in the passwd file set to '/var/www' for my username. Changed it to my own home directory. Seems valid to me :) ... thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Tensineer great please upvote the comment.

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal, unfortunately it happens for unknown reason, but while your comment provides a solution I think it will be worth to convert it into an answer.

Comment: In addition to what pa4080 says: it seems I'm not able to upvote comments. But an answer should be upvotable for me, I assume.

Comment: @pa4080 thank you I am posting this in the answer section.

Comment: Thanks, @PrinceKumarBarnwal. Now Tensineer could mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: I'd just set an alias with a different name if 'cd ~' doesn't work and if the new name does the same thing. like alias hh=' cd /home/<user>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `/etc/passwd` file and change directory location for `tensineer` user but for this, you must have `sudo` privileges.

Hope this will work for you.